# Effectively replace values of dataframe column with relative frequency in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a huge dataset (~7 Gb) and I need EFFECTIVELY replace one variable (iser id) by relative frequency (i.e. freq(user_id) / unique(user_id)). Minimal example:

```
id <- c(1050, 1324, 5, 7, 1050, 7, 8)
table(id)
```

```
id
   5    7    8 1050 1324 
   1    2    1    2    1
```

Then I tried

```
freq <- ave(id, id, FUN = function(X) length(X) / length(unique(id)))
df <- data.frame(id = id, freq = freq)
```

Output:

```
    id freq
1 1050  0.4
2 1324  0.2
3    5  0.2
4    7  0.4
5 1050  0.4
6    7  0.4
7    8  0.2
```

But on my data set this solution has been working for three(!) hours already. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe try `prop.table(table(id))`?

Comment: This gives another values, but it's possible option. Ty for idea! But how can I apply it to all df column?

Comment: Yes, because you are dividing with the unique length instead of the length...Also you only show 1 column (`id`) in your example. Make sure your examples reflect your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tidyverse implementation:

```
library(tidyverse)
id <- c(1050, 1324, 5, 7, 1050, 7, 8)

data_frame( id = id)-> my_df # creating df

  my_df%>% 
    mutate(unique =  unique(id) %>% length) %>% # addying column unique, with the number of unique id
  group_by(id) %>%                              # group by id
  mutate(
    n=n(),                                      # number of observations for the current group         
    freq = n / unique                           # n / unique gives the freq
    )
```

if you want to learn more about group_by check this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70UcgabaB_I&t=14s

Answer (score 0):

An option could be using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1050,1324,5,7,1050,7,8), 
                 freq = c(0.4,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.2))
sqldf('SELECT id, freq / Count(*) FROM df
       GROUP BY id, freq')
```